# Integral involving a trig. term

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across the following integral.
$$
\int\frac{dx}{1+\sin x}
$$

I have no idea how to solve it! I went for the obvious substitution of $u=1+\sin x$, but then you get an annoying $\cos x$ kicking around. I tried to eliminate this by writing $\cos x=\sqrt{1-(u-1)^2}$, but I couldn't get this idea to work.

Answer (score 6):

Multiply up and down by $1-\sin{x}$:

$$\int dx \frac{1-\sin{x}}{1-\sin^2{x}} = \int dx \left ( \sec^2{x} - \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}} \right ) = \tan{x} - \sec{x} + C$$

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you've written the $dx$ to the left of the function you are trying to integrate matter? (I understand what you're saying, and my comment is entirely tangential: I just feel that what you've written doesn't actually makes sense, but would be interested if my intuition was wrong...)

Comment: @user1729: I feel it's incidental, but is a great comfort to me personally.  If you can cook up some reason why it violates some logic, then by all means.  But I am OK with it.

Comment: @user1729 the notation that you've commented on gets used quite a bit when the integral is treated like an operator (which it often is). I don't know if it's as bad as $\sin^2(x)$ being the square of the sine rather than the sine of the sine, but we are stuck with it nonetheless. Ron Gordon, you correctly put the integrand in parentheses which you wouldn't have had to do if $dx$ was on the right. There is no logical violation if one is consistent with that.

Answer (score 5):

HINT :

$$\frac{1}{1+\sin x}=\frac{1}{1+\sin x}\cdot\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}$$
For the second, set $t=\cos x$.

Comment: The second term is just $\tan x\sec x$, which is the derivative of $\sec x$

Comment: @Dylan: You are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**
$$\int\frac{dx}{1+\cos (\pi/2-x)}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dx}{\cos^2 (\pi/4-x/2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})\\ \sin x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2} \\ \cos x=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$ now , in this case
$$u=\tan(\frac{x}{2}) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2}))dx=du \rightarrow  dx=\frac{2du}{1+u^2}\\\frac{1}{1+\sin x}dx=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2u}{1+u^2}}\frac{2du}{1+u^2}=\frac{2du}{1+u^2+2u}\\=\frac{2du}{(1+u)^2}$$so 
$$\int \frac{1}{1+ \sin x}dx=\int\frac{2du}{(1+u)^2}=-2\frac{1}{1+u} +c$$